# How can I extract the html code for a DOM object generated by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am generating a svg object in a html document using java script. Something like this:

```
mySvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
myPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
mySvg.appendChild(myPath);
```

Is there a javascript command to extract what the resulting html code would be?

i.e.

```
"<svg>...<path>...</path>...</svg>"
```

I want to then save this part as a string variable.

Thanks, Wendy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah...Put your svg tag into a div and then get the Html of that div.

```
<div id="container"></div>
$('#container').append('mySvg');
```

And for the whole svg as an html, you can do this:

```
var svgHtml = $('#container').html();
```

For the string:

```
var svgHtml = document.getElementById('container').innerText;
```

Comment: +1 - yeah, I would go with `outerHTML` but that's the way. also see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the innerHTML to get the html text for an element

```
mySvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
myPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
mySvg.appendChild(myPath);

document.getElementById('x').appendChild(mySvg);

console.log(document.getElementById('x').innerHTML)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q84Bp/)